# Does the given time complexity solvable by simplifying the constants?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

So we're given this

`O(T(n))` if `T(n)=T(n−1)+3n+1` for `n>0` and `T(0)=1`

and we need to determine the Big-O Notation for this. However, I've tried solving it but I'm having a problem with the constants when I tried simplifying it. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what problems did you have? This isnt a question about c++

Comment: Big O notation is approximate. It determines complexity for very large input. So for O(2*n+3*n)  we really don't care about sum and multiplication here as n number has direct impact on complexity. Big O is therefore O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The constants are irrelevant with Big-O notation. O(T(n)) = O(T(n-1)) + O(n).

Answer (score 0):

`O(n) = sum(i*3 + 1), 0 <= i <= n` which can be simplified to

`O(n) = n+1 + 3*sum(i), 0 <= i <= n` after evaluating the sum we get

`O(n) = n+1 + 3*n(n+1)/2` then rearrange the terms to arrive at

```
O(n) = 3/2*n2 + 5/2*n + 1
```